# How to get Memory Usage for a PID in a variable using bash

Tags: bash, shell, openwrt, command-substitution

This is what I've been working with but haven't been successful,

```
if [ "$memUsage" -gt "30500" ];
    then
        transUsage=$(pmap 3097 | tail -n 1 | awk '/[0-9]/{print $2}')
        transUsage=$transUsage | awk '/[0-9]/{print $2}' #This was my attempt at removing the extra K
        if [ "$transUsage" -gt "10500" ];
        then
        echo "Terminated this and this"
        fi
    # Print the usage
    echo "Memory Usage: $memUsage KB"
    fi
```

I need memory usage of PID 3097 in variable so that I could use if command.
Currently it outputs,

```
xxxxK, where x is memory usage size. Due to K being part of size, it's not being being recognized as numeric value.
```

How to solve this? Would appreciate the help.
Regards!

Comment: If you do not need the value for `transUsage` outside this bock of code, then you may be able to generate this output with a single `awk` command:   `pmap $pid | awk 'END{gsub(/K/, " KB", $2); if($2>10500){print "Terminated this and this"}; print "Memory Usage "$2}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this better code:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$1

transUsage=$(pmap $pid | awk 'END{sub(/K/, "", $2); print $2}')
if ((transUsage > 10500)); then
    echo "Terminated this and this"
fi

echo "Memory Usage: $transUsage KB"
```

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression.